# Correcting photo number sequence

Tags: iphone

I have approximately 1100 photos on file.

At number 1291 the numbering jumped to 3300s

How can I correct the number to read the next view as 1291? And so on.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, and welcome to AskDifferent. Are you trying to change the file names of the photos in the Finder, or the photo names in the Photos app, or the numbers used in future photos?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the number stored in

```
~/Library/Media/PhotoData/MISC/DCIM_APPLE.plist
```

The integer value is stored under the key `DCIMLastFileNumber`.

This property list is accessible from a backup, so you can backup your iPhone with iTunes, modify the backup, and then restore from backup. If your device is jailbroken, you can edit the file directly on the device.

[image]
[image]